# Dynamically Changing Variation Price Not Working in WooCommerce 3.x

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, price, product-variations

I'm at the end of my rope here. My client applied the update to WooCommerce 3.x, and now a custom plugin I had isn't working. The plugin essentially added a certain amount to the price of a product based on the user's postal code. It will work for regular products, but not for variable/variation products. I know the filters for "woocommerce_get_price" has changed, but I can't see any mention of "woocommerce_variation_prices_price" being changed or deprecated.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated. The plugin worked fine until the update to 3.x.

Here are the filters that were working fine before:

add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price','zp_custom_variation_prices_price', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price','zp_custom_variation_prices_price', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_sale_price','zp_custom_variation_prices_price', 10, 2);

The zp_custom_variation_prices_price function spits out a new price based on their location for each variation. I have confirmed that this function properly spits out the adjusted price for each of the variations. The filters just don't seem to apply the price with the adjustment.

At a loss here. Thanks in advance.

**Update: May 15th**

I think I may have found a solution to the issue, with a lot of trial and error (and a little bit of crying).

Here are the filters that finally worked:

> add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price','zp_custom_variation_prices_price', 10, 2);
> >add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price','zp_custom_variation_prices_price', 10, 2);
> >add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price','zp_custom_variation_prices_price', 10, 2);

I'm not entirely sure how the plugin worked before, but this seems to have taken care of it. I don't see anything in the documentation about this for WooCommerce, but there it is.

**end update**

Comment: Those filters still exist. Can you share the `zp_custom_variation_prices_price` function code? Have you cleared transients?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Here is the code from the function:

// Callback for variable product prices
function zp_custom_variation_prices_price($variation_price, $variation, $product) {
 global $amount;
 global $new_price;
 $new_price = $variation_price;
 // Return the price plus the $amount
 if( $variation_price && !in_local_zips() )
   $new_price += $amount;
   return $new_price;

}

Comment: Here is the one thing additional. Right now I have the price range hidden on the order page, but if I 'unhide' it, the price is actually correct (with the added values), it's the price that shows up once you choose the variation elements that is the wrong price. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the function. It's so hard to read code in the comments.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, this is my first post on here! I actually have found a solution I think, and I'll post it above as well.